# How to transform the table in R?

Tags: r

here is my data.txt:

```
country   attitude   count  
china   a   52  
china   b   58  
china   c   25  
china   d   12  
china   e   3  
china   f   1  
france  a   35  
france  b   48  
france  c   40  
france  d   21  
france  e   9  
france  f   2  
india   a   96  
india   b   28  
india   c   13  
india   d   7  
india   e   10  
india   f   0   
england a   21  
england b   41  
england c   50  
england d   23  
england e   18  
england f   3  
usa         a   31  
usa         b   48  
usa         c   45  
usa         d   19  
usa         e   10  
usa         f   3
```

I want to get the table 1:

```
attitude    count
a   235
b   223
c   173
d   82
e   50
f   9
```

And the table 2:

```
       a    b   c     d   e  f
china   52  58  25  12  3   1
france  35  48  40  21  9   2
india   96  28  13  7   10  0
england 21  41  50  23  18  3
usa 31  48  45  19  10  3
```

How can i transform data.txt into the two  tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table 1:

```
aggregate(count~attitude,data=data.txt,FUN=sum)
  attitude count
1        a   235
2        b   223
3        c   173
4        d    82
5        e    50
6        f     9
```

Table 2:

```
xtabs(count~country+attitude,data.txt)
         attitude
country    a  b  c  d  e  f
  china   52 58 25 12  3  1
  england 21 41 50 23 18  3
  france  35 48 40 21  9  2
  india   96 28 13  7 10  0
  usa     31 48 45 19 10  3
```

Or if you are wanting a new data.frame:

```
reshape(data.txt,direction="wide",timevar="attitude",idvar="country")
   country count.a count.b count.c count.d count.e count.f
1    china      52      58      25      12       3       1
7   france      35      48      40      21       9       2
13   india      96      28      13       7      10       0
19 england      21      41      50      23      18       3
25     usa      31      48      45      19      10       3
```

Comment: my data is in the "/home/debian/data.txt",aggregate(count~attitude,data="/home/debian/data.txt",FUN=sum)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : invalid 'envir' argument
how can i do?

Comment: @BqsjSjbq I used `data.txt` as a variable name for want of a better name. It is not a link to the file. Use `data.txt <- read.table("/home/debian/data.txt",header=T)` to read the file in.

Answer (score 1):

Using Hadley's packages,

```
plyr::ddply(d, .(attitude), summarise, n = sum(count))

reshape2::dcast(d, country ~ attitude)
```